# pass joomla article id to modal iframe form

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, components

I have a view in my joomla 2.5 component and a form at this.
now I'm show this form pop up in my article by this code by use joomla modal and it's work

```
<a class="modal"  rel="{handler: \'iframe\', size: {x: 600, y: 375}}" href='.$formlink.'>my text</a>
```

now how can I send my article id to this form for insert it to my database?
I want pass my article id to iframe form.

Answer (score 1):

i found how can do it.
we can do it use this code:

```
$id = $article->id; $formlink = JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview&tmpl=component&id=$id")
```